# How to do a simple get query using SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I want to do a simple get query where I get a user by its Id:

My current query is this:

```
        user = configurations.session.query(UserModel).filter_by(id=1)
        result = configurations.session.execute(user)
        for u in configurations.session.query(UserModel).instances(result):
            print u
```

where configurations is the settings file that has a session instance of the database and the UserModel is the user class.

Even though the code is right, and works fine, isn't it just too much to do a get query? Shouldn't an ORM make it as easy as: `user.get(id=1)` ?

Comment: and if you mean something like `UserModel.get(id = 1)`? Unfortunately I don't think SQLAlchemy has any such convenience function. I had to build my own function `objGetter` which did all the messy stuff inside.

Answer (score 3):

Note: As far as I know the primary key must be of the right type.

user = Session.query (UserModel).get (1)

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
user = configurations.session.query(UserModel).filter_by(id=1).one()
```